# jquery drag/drop - activate dropzone with mouse not with center of dragged element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i want to drop some elements to another element.
my problem is the dropzone only gets activated when the middle of the dragged element is entering the dropzone.
the wished behaviour is to get the dropzone activated as soon as the mouse enters/hovers the dropzone.

i'm pretty shure this is a no brainer, but not for me...

i tried different options as example:

```
cursorAt: 
snap:
handle:
```

but none of them helped anything...
i've just created a jsfiddle to explain my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/FxEm7/3/

many thanks and kind regards
costal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `tolerance` option for droppable and set its value to `pointer`, as below:

```
$("#drop1, #drop2, #drop3").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    handle: ".msgHandler",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        console.log("msg_id = "+ui.helper[0].id);
        console.log("drop_id = "+this.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: No worries. It's not like there's not a bazillion different options to worry about. :) Please make sure to vote up and accept answers that solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

The correct tolerance value is "touch".

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance

Comment: thank you very much, i was looking for the "pointer" tolerance